# OpenCV: Is there any way to extract the real world x coordinate of a point from a depth map

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

Is there any way to extract the real world X coordinate of a point from a depth map of a calibrated stereo camera rig given only the baseline B, the focal length f and the real world depth "Z" computed from Z=f(B)(x-x') where x - x' is the disparity computed from the column indices of their respective images obtained from matching details from the left and right cameras?

Comment: is the baseline (position) given in real world coordinates?

Comment: can you sketch you stereo cam setup?

Comment: If Z is expressed in the camera frame of the left camera and x the coordinate in the image frame of the left image, you should be able to compute the coordinate in the normalized camera frame (z=1) with the intrinsic matrix and then calculate the X and Y by multiplying them with the Z coordinate. If what you want is the coordinate in an object/world frame, you have to know the camera pose.